# Google "Sitelinks" for a website with almost only dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search

I have a classifieds website, and the index.html is just going to be a simle form, which uses javascript alot to populate drop lists etc...

I have a menu also, put into a div container, but is this enough?

I mean, I have no content in index.html (almost), but a search form, which submits to a search results page, where all the content is.

So I am worried google might not find suitable sitelinks for my site?

Anybody know if I need to add something to the links in the index.html, which google might use for sitelinks? title tags etc...?

Thanks

Comment: does your form use post or get to send the form data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing your site around you can just create a good sitemap.xml file.  That is of course if you're using GET for transferring data to your processing page.  I would create a dynamic sitemap.xml page that is based on the form data that your processing page can read.

http://sitemaps.org/

http://www.smart-it-consulting.com/article.htm?node=133&page=37